# implement a node list in Perl

Tags: perl, list, implementation

I wrote the following module but am not sure how to refer to the "last" and "head" nodes.  As well as storing the address of the next node in "{nextNode}" in the previous node.

I am trying to save the reference of the class when storing it but later it's complaining: "Not a HASH reference at List.pm"; which I understand why but am not sure how the syntax would be.

If I de-reference $head and $last ($$last->{nextNode} = \$class) then I think it's using the actual name of my class; List and not the previous object like I want to.

```
package List;

my $head = undef;
my $last = undef;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    # init the head of the list
    if ($head == undef) {
    $head = \$class;
    print "updated head to:$head", "\n";
    }

    $last = \$class;
    $last->{nextNode} = \$class; # update previous node to point on this new one    

    print "updated last to:$last", "\n";
    my $self = {};
    $self->{value} = shift;    
    $self->{nextNode} = ""; # reset next to nothing since this node is last

    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be storing `$self` everywhere instead of `\$class`.  Storing $class is simply storing the name of the class, not the object itself.

Also, for `$self->{nextNode}` I'd store an `undef` instead of a blank string.  Or better yet, simply don't create it at all and use [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) when checking if it is there.

Answer (score 3):

You're over thinking it. If you use an array for your list instead of a hash, you don't need to worry about the *head* and *last*. The head of an array is `$array[0]` and the last member is `$array[-1]`. Simple and easy to do.

Here's a quick standard class definition for defining a list. I've only defined a constructor (the new subroutine) and one method (the list).

```
package Local::List;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;

   my $self = {};
   bless $self, $class;
   $self->list([]);
}

sub list {
   my $self = shift;
   my $list_ref = shift;

   if (ref $list_ref ne "ARRAY) {
       return;
   }
   if (defined $list_ref) {
       $self->{LIST} = $list_ref;
   }
   if wantarray {
      return $self->{LIST};
   }
}
```

The first thing: Use the same standard names everyone else uses. Use `new` for the *constructor*. When I try to look at the documentation on how to use your class, I can search for the word *new* and know that's how I create a class object. Also, use the variable names `$class` and `$self`. That's what everyone else does, so it's easy to know what's going on.

Notice in my `new` subroutine, the first item passed is the name of the class while the first item passed to my other subroutines is a reference to my class object (i.e. `$self`). That's probably the hardest thing to understand about classes.

Notice in `new`, I immediately create my `$self` and bless it. That way, I can call my other subroutines (my methods) to do the setting for me. This way, my constructor doesn't know how my class is structured. This has a lot of advantages:

- When (not if) I modify my class, I don't have to modify the constructor.
- My constructor is always in sync with all of my methods.
- I don't have to know how my class object is structured when I start defining the class. I can start writing my class without worrying about all those dirty details on how it'll work.

Notice that the `list` subroutine (or method) can either set a list or return a list. It's much easier if you use the same subroutine to set or get the value. Also in your method subroutines, use a blank return when your method function returns an error. Otherwise, always return something. That makes it easy to test to see if a method failed or not.

Let's look at some of the other *methods* you probably want to have. Let's have all the four standard list functions:

- push
- pop
- shift
- unshift

Here's an example:

```
sub push {
    my $self = shift;
    my $member = shift;

    if (not defined $member) {
        return;
    }

    my $list_ref = $self->list;
    my $return = push @{ $list_ref }, $member;
    $self->list($list_ref);

    return $return;
}
```

Wow, that's simple. Notice that the `pop` doesn't know what my class looks like. It used the `list` method to retrieve a list reference. Then it used the builtin `push` method to push a member onto the list. I save that return value, and that's what I'll return. I'm not even sure what `push` returns. All I know is that push returns **something** if it succeeds. (Yes, I know it returns the number of items in the list).

The other three functions are more or less the same. Here's a few more:

- current
- splice
- next
- previous
- head
- last

All you need to do for *current* is to store the current value. Use the same function to set and get the value. Notice that my `list` method or my `push` method, or my `new` constructor knows or care how you store it. Nor, do our `next` and `previous` methods. All they need to do is increment or decrement the value of `current` and store it back using the `current` method subroutine:

```
sub next {
   my $self = shift

   my @list = $self->list;  #Returns a list;
   my $current = $self->current;
   my $list_size = $#list;

   if ($current eq $list_size) {
      return;   #Can't return a value after the end of the list!
   }

   $current++;  #Increment the value;
   my $value = $list[$current];  #I'll return this
   $self->current($current) #Store the new current
   return $value;
}
```

And, now to the basis of your question: Getting the last and head values of the list. Here's last

```
sub last {
   my $self = shift;

   my $list_ref = $self->list;
   return ${ $list_ref }[-1];
}
```

And a quick copy and paste will give me head:

```
sub head {
   my $self = shift;

   my $list_ref = $self->list;
   return ${ $list_ref }[0];
}
```

That's it! All that worrying you were doing was for naught.

Sorry for the long post. I just wanted to emphasize that object oriented programming in Perl isn't that tricky as long as you follow a few simple guide lines.

(Simple? What about `use Moose;` No, I said *simple*!). ;-)

Comment: Your solution is very interesting.  Thanks for the hard work (simple for you ;) ).  Just one question though: what if you want to store more than one value? Let's say you want to store a phone book...

Comment: @YanivBenDavid  A phone book as a single value for a list member or storing a phone book in a list? Let's say you want to store a phone book in a list (or maybe a phonebook entry). There's nothing in my method that restricts you from storing a reference to your phonebook or even better a phone book object from your phonebook class. If you're talking about storing a list of phone book entries, you can use the `Local::List->list` method to set the entire list to be your phonebook.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post my final working version for the record and for your feedback/comments.
Thanks again!!

```
package List;

my $head = undef;
my $last = undef;

sub new {
    my ($class, $val) = @_;
    my $self = {};

    # init the head of the list
    if (!defined $head) {
    $head = $self;
    print "updated the head of the list ($head)" . "\n";
    }
    else {
    $last->{nextNode} = $self; # update previous node to point on this new one
    }

    $last = $self; # this object is now the last one

    $self->{value} = $val; # store the value
    $self->{nextNode} = undef; # reset next to nothing since this node is last

    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub setVal {
    my ($class, $val) = @_;
    $class->{value} = $val;
}

sub getVal {
    my $class = shift;
    print $class->{value};
}

sub getNext {
    my $class = shift;
    return $class->{nextNode};
}

# return true if this is the last node, otherwise false.
sub isLast {
    my $class = shift;
    return 1 if !defined $class->{nextNode};
    return 0;
}

sub getLast {
    return $last;
}

sub getHead {
    return $head;
}

# looping through all the list and printing the values
sub showList {
    my $node = $head; # set temp node to the head

    while ( !$node->isLast() ) {
    print $node->{value} . "\n";
    $node = $node->{nextNode};
    }

    # printing last value. (should be defined but I check it just in case)
    print $node->{value} . " (last)\n" if defined $node->{value};
}

1;
```

Script:

```
my $n0 = new List(4);
my $n1 = new List(8);
my $n2 = new List(9);
my $n3 = new List(3);
my $n4 = new List(1);
my $n5 = new List(0);
my $n6 = new List(5);
print "\nShow list: \n";
$n2->showList(); # any object will print the list
```